# How to add WPF Jumplist to Jump Path?

Tags: c#, wpf, jump-list

How to add WPF window Jumplist jumpPath?
My code:

```
JumpList jumpList = new JumpList();
jumpList.ShowRecentCategory = true;
jumpList.ShowFrequentCategory = true;
JumpList.SetJumpList(Application.Current, jumpList);

JumpPath jumpPath = new JumpPath();
jumpPath.Path = @"C:\see.txt";
jumpList.JumpItems.Add(jumpPath);
jumpList.Apply();
```

Not show my application this file "C:\see.txt".
But add jumptask show my application. Example:

```
JumpTask jumpTask = new JumpTask();
jumpTask.Title = "Notepad";
jumpTask.Description = "JumpTask to open Notepad";
jumpTask.ApplicationPath = @"%windir%\system32\notepad.exe";
jumpTask.IconResourcePath = @"%windir%\system32\notepad.exe";
jumpTask.IconResourceIndex = 0;
jumpList.Apply();
```

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RqY1G.png)
How to use JumpPath in wpf?

Comment: Is your application standing as your default application for opening .txt files?  If you add a JumpPath to a .txt file, your application must be registered to handle .txt files by default.

Comment: Mmm... I understand. My project that I want to store recent list because open file and add to listview. Thanks!